# Does this transformation have an inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, fourier-series, transformation

Let $f(n)$ be a complex sequence.  Then for prime $p$ define $\hat{f}(p) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n e^{-i 2 \pi n / p}$.  Then let the transformation of sequences be $T$, i.e. $Tf = \hat{f}$.  Is there an inverse transform?  The transformation result sequence is complex, indexed by the primes.

In other words, does the infinite matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
z^{k/p_j} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ where }
z = e^{-i 2 \pi}
\text{ and element $z^{k/p_j}$ is in row $j$, column $k$, $p_j$ is the $j$th prime.}
$$
have an inverse.

How would you solve this?

Let's relax the restriction that $\hat{f}$ sequence must be prime indexed and say it has the same index as $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if finite dimensioned square matrices of this form have an inverse.

Let $A = $

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
z^{1/2} & z \\
z^{1/3} & z^{2/3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It's $\det$ is $z^{1/2}z^{2/3} - zz^{1/3} = z^{7/6} - z^{4/3} \neq 0$ since $z^{7/6 - 4/3 = -1/6} \neq 1$.

It's inverse is 
$\cdots$

This seems tedious.  A computer should do it.